Use external documentation for endpoint in Swagger UI
For a specific endpoint in our REST API I'd like to provide external documentation.
There is an argument external_docs that can be passed to the extend_schema, but I haven't seen any example anywhere.
I passed just the URL to the external documentation:
@extend_schema_view(
    my_specific_endpoint=extend_schema(
        external_docs="https://documentation.example.com"
    )
)
class MySpecificViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # class contents

The clients should use the external documentation to get instructions on using it.
This endpoint cannot be used through the Swagger UI and ideally the button "Try it out" should be disabled, if that's possible.
Additionally, I'd like to disable the Parameters and the Response sections too.
EDIT:
The argument external_docs accepts a dictionary with specific keys too:
external_docs={"url": "https://documentation.example.com", "description": "API documentation"}

But I am still looking for an option to disable the button "Try it out", or the button "Execute".
